# MySQL union and left join combined

Tags: mysql, sql

DB Structure

```
users
------
user_id
contact_person
company
timestamp

trading
--------
user_id
timestamp
buying_selling
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to query the db

I am looking to build a timeline of events that pulls in data from my signups and trading board.

Both have timestamps that I need to put in order and add in the user info (who posted / joined)

The user info table also has a timestamp of when they joined.

I am struggling with the query, this is what I think I need (syntax not right as im not sure how to do it)

```sql
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 'signup' as type FROM users
UNION 
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 'trade' as type FROM trading
lEFT JOIN
company, contact_person FROM users
ON user_id
```

This is what I tried (not quite right)

```sql
SELECT
*
FROM
users
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 'signup' as type FROM users
UNION 
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 'trade' as type FROM trading
) foo ON users.user_id = foo.user_id
```

I hashed this together from looking at other posts but its not quite right as it pulls in all the user info and I end up with two timestamps that I cant order.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` syntax is incorrect in that first query you posted.   If you can provide information as to the structure/relationships of the company and contact person tables to the trading table, I can provide you the proper syntax for your union query.

Comment: I have updated with the basic table structure, I am trying to make a list of ids, timestamps and whether it was a signup or trade. Once I have my list - left join the user info back by the user id. All rows need to be sorted by timestamp desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT user_id, contact_person, company, timestamp, 'signup' type 
  FROM users
 UNION ALL
SELECT t.user_id, u.contact_person, u.company, t.timestamp, 'trade' 
  FROM trading t JOIN users u
    ON t.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5618/1)** demo